Google Cloud Run ignores USER command in Dockerfile, runs as root
I'm using the USER command in Dockerfile to switch the user from root to the newly created user (and group) apprunner.
Problem is, after my latest deployment on Friday Nov 7th 2024, Cloud Run is running the container not as apprunner, but as root.
When I pull the same container from the GCP registry and run it locally, it runs as apprunner. If in console I press "Edit & deploy new revision" and without changes just press the "Deploy" button at the bottom, Cloud Run starts container as apprunner. Even If I then allocate traffic to the revision that was running as root, it will start running as apprunner.
The interesting thing is that within the Cloud Run Service Revision which is starting containers as root, a container is started as apprunner with about 1/20 probability.
I'm using Terraform google_cloud_run_service resource to deploy the service (not v2). First generation execution environment (default). This happens for images in both Container Registry and Artifact Registry. The image is referred to by a tag which Cloud Run then internally resolves into a permanent SHA hash (I am sure the tag is correct, I tested the same URL locally). Region is europe-west3.
I also took two-week-old code which deployed fine and pushed it to deploy again, and it exhibits the same behavior now.
I am at a loss. Docker USER command documentation states that it also selects the user to run the ENTRYPOINT and CMD commands under, but seems like this is no longer the case for Cloud Run? Could I have read or been notified about this breaking change somewhere? Or am I missing some configuration that I need to set?
Here's the simplified Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11-slim

RUN mkdir /app &&\
    adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" apprunner &&\
    chown -R apprunner /app

# root
RUN whoami

USER apprunner

# apprunner
RUN whoami

ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-c"]

# Cloud Run: root, Local: apprunner
CMD ["whoami"]

To test locally:
docker build -f test.Dockerfile -t test_whoami .
docker run --rm test_whoami


the 1/20 probability is a problem... And strange... Did you try with the 2nd gen execution runtime?

Since about 24 hours ago the issue is no longer present. Guess, Google fixed it
